# How to retrieve image in a gridview from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-imageview

I am just retrieving image from the `drawable` and using a `base adapter` but the `fragment` doesn't show any `image`. Following is my code... is there any problem or logical error... Can someone tell me!!!
Here is fragment code ..

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_question, container, false);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mContext);
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and here is the adapter code

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the getItem(..) method in your adapter to this and see how it goes.

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: My problem is solved by using 
 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getactivity()); 

 .... Thank you  Eric Liu...